# Graphical error on moving from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, graphics

I was on ubuntu 11.10, I have tried to update the OS to 12.04 (with 12.04.1 version). All has worked, except the fact that when I reboot :

- I stay blocked on the loading page
- I can access the consol mode (ctrl-alt-F1)
  If I try to restart the graphic interface, it freezes completely, but it appears (no more keyboard, no mouse)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the Shift key while your computer is booting up, and don't let go until it actually shows the grub menu

choose recovery mode and from there update your system using `sudo apt-get update` and check for the problem by reviewing `dmesg`

Comment: I have done sudo `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It still does not work. The `dmesg` command gives many lines and in particular : `init : gdm main process (1197) killed TERM signal` and `init : lightdm main process (1198) killed TERM signal